# Why is it better to use the symfony/filesystem component with PHP?

Tags: php

I would like to understand why I should use `symfony/filesystem` and depend on a third-party package with:

```
$fileSystem->mkdir('/tmp/foo', 0700);
```

When I can simply do:

```
mkdir('/tmp/foo', 0700);
```

Is there any advantage that compensates the additional complexity I get?

Comment: If you can simply do - then why do you even use symfony?

Comment: I noticed most frameworks even the smallest use this symfony package. When I look at the code of Laravel I just don't understand how complex it is for so little. I would like to understand, and this example could lead me to the anwser

Comment: Of course you can use `mkdir`, direct access to `$_POST` and all other stuff. But the point is that when you use some library, other programmers who will use your code later will be aware what to expect: okay, he's using symfony component - then I can find it in  the code. It's called __consistnecy__ - everywhere in your code you use __one__ approach. It can be symfony component, other component or pure `mkdir`.

Comment: Yeah it could be true, but I am updating an old application that was developed bare-metal in PHP/JS. Now I use `SASS`, `Composer`, `npmjs`, plenty of packages, `JQuery`, `Bootstrap`, `Webix`, ... I am starting to realize that the amount of knowledge you need to maintain this application is huge in comparison with the original application. Meaning, now I have short methods, everything looks clear to me, but not to my colleagues that had never done web development before. The trade-off is very hard to find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, using the Symfony/Filesystem API, you have a more closely object-oriented approach and I can see, at least, 3 benefits:

1 - It makes easier to handle the directory creation itself. Just send which directory you want to create and mode.

2 - The errors are thrown as exceptions.

3 - It's easier to mock the `mkdir` behavior when you are unit testing.